# What does a CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User: Error mean?

Tags: python, twitter, error-handling

I'm a beginner with coding.

I'm trying to scrape tweets from a Twitter account.

I'm getting the following error when I run my code:  `CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User:`

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
import twint 

config = twint.Config()
    # Search tweets tweeted by user 'BarackObama'
config.Username = "BarackObama"
    # Limit search results to 20
config.Limit = 20
    # Return tweets that were published after Jan 1st, 2020
config.Since = "2020-01-1 20:30:15"
    # Formatting the tweets
config.Format = "Tweet Id {id}, tweeted at {time}, {date}, by {username} says: {tweet}"
    # Storing tweets in a csv file
config.Store_csv = True
config.Output = "Barack Obama"    

twint.run.Search(config)
```

Does this error mean it's a problem with Twint, or is there a mistake in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: have you found a solution for this error?

Answer (score 7):

I'm a beginner as well, trying to learn python as a tool for Digital History in Brazil.
I was getting the same problem (only when using c.Username parameter).
I solved running `pip3 install --upgrade -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint`

I hope it works for you.

Comment: never expected this. What kind of problem it is? It is just a different way to install a Twint (as written on READ.me on Twint GitHub repo). Smh.. but anyway thank you. I spent almost 6 hours on this stup-

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in modifying user.py in the twint source, and replace lines  with a try and except statement.

```
try:
    _usr.name = ur['data']['user']['legacy']['name']
except:
    _usr.name = ''
try:
    _usr.username = ur['data']['user']['legacy']['screen_name']
except:
    _usr.username = ''
try:
    _usr.bio = ur['data']['user']['legacy']['description']
except:
    _usr.bio = ''
try:
    _usr.location = ur['data']['user']['legacy']['location']
except:
    _usr.location = ''
try: 
    _usr.url = ur['data']['user']['legacy']['url']
except:
    _usr.url = ''
```

Comment: I find that I can scrape ~250 records before a block happens. I then wait for 5 ~ 10 mins before it lifts.